# php array in javascript variable for jquery autocomplete

Tags: php, javascript

I am using jquery autocomplete and trying to define the values for the auto complete options.

I am trying to create a javascript variable from a php array.
So far i have:

```
<?php
$usernames = get_records_sql("SELECT firstname,lastname FROM {$CFG->prefix}user ORDER BY lastname DESC");    
?>

<script language="javascript">
var names = ['<?php echo $usernames; ?>'];
</script>
```

I just need to convert the array to this format

```
var names= ["firstname lastname", "firstname lastname", "firstname lastname"];
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `<?php echo $usernames; ?>`?

Comment: Array ( [testing] => stdClass Object ( [lastname] => testing [firstname] => testing ) [test] => stdClass Object ( [lastname] => testing [firstname] => test ) [ab-temp] => stdClass Object ( [lastname] => test [firstname] => ab-temp ) )

Comment: Can't see how this can be converted directly to JS array - looks like Peter answer has most chances to do what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var names = [<?php 
    $tmp = Array();
    foreach($usernames as $row) $tmp[] = '"'.$row->firstname.' '.$row->lastname.'"'; 
    echo join(',', $tmp);
?>];
```

Comment: hi peter, thanks for the answer. I cant get it working though. $usernames outputs as - Array ( [testing] => stdClass Object ( [lastname] => testing [firstname] => testing ) [test] => stdClass Object ( [lastname] => testing [firstname] => test ) [ab-temp] => stdClass Object ( [lastname] => test [firstname] => ab-temp ) )

Comment: Ok so your rows are objects (not arrays). So you may use `$row->column_name` instead `$row['column_name']`. I updated my answer.

Comment: :) thank you very much, it works like a dream. I should have known that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) function to encode a PHP array to a JavaScript array.

You can modify the below code to your specifications:

```
$arr = array();
// depending on the value get_records_sql() returns, you may have to modify
// this loop:
foreach($usernames as $row)
{
    $arr[] = $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'];
}
$output = json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: he wants "firstname lastname"

Answer (score 0):

This should work (untested)

```
foreach ($usernames as $key => $row) {
    $user[] = $row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'];
}

echo "<script language=\"javascript\">var names = ['" . implode(',',$user) . "'];</script>";
```

Cycle through rows, append each name to array $user, implode the array into a string and output.